# Calculate the sum of dates in a sequence (1/day, after one another)

Tags: mysql

I'd like to write a query that calculates how many of them are in sequence (ie. finds out how many days are in a row before the chain breaks) starting from todays date and going backwards in time. The same date is only occurring once in the DB.

Example (today's date is 2012-07-15 here):

```
2012-07-14
2012-07-13
2012-07-10
```

= 2

```
2012-07-14
2012-07-13
2012-07-12
2012-07-10
2012-07-09
```

= 3

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) value of the date..

```
<?php

$userDate = "2012-07-14";

$pastDate = strtotime($userDate);
$currentTime  = time();
$secondsSince = round($currentTime-$pastDate);
$daysSince    = $secondsSince/86400; // 86400 being the seconds in a day

$preciseNumDays = sprintf("%.2f", $daysSince);

echo $preciseNumDays;

?>
```

I just wrote that simple script to calculate the number of days since the past date.. You could loop an array of days and get the days since each date passed through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in sql server.. please convert it to mysql syntax

```
 select count(*) from
(select dateval,DATEDIFF(day,dateval,'2012-07-15') day_diff,
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dateval desc) as rownum from test_11 )a
where a.rownum=a.day_diff
```